# My android application keeps force closing when running a specific class

Tags: java, android

App keeps force closing every time I try to run this class. When I run this class on an android device or an emulator, it will tell me that the app has stopped. It works perfectly fine before this class is run. Android Studio is showing me no errors.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Predictions {

    private static Predictions predictions;
    private String[] answers;
    public ImageView ball;
    public TextView answerText;
    public Animation animationslideintop;

    private Predictions() {
       int randomNumber = (int) ((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
      if (randomNumber == 1) {
        answerText.setText("");
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball02);
            }
        }, 100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball03);
            }
        }, 200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball04);
            }
        }, 300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball05);
            }
        }, 400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball06);
            }
        }, 500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball07);
            }
        }, 600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball08);
            }
        }, 700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball09);
            }
        }, 800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball10);
            }
        }, 900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball11);
            }
        }, 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball12);
            }
        }, 1100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball13);
            }
        }, 1200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball14);
            }
        }, 1300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball15);
            }
        }, 1400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball16);
            }
        }, 1500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball17);
            }
        }, 1600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball18);
            }
        }, 1700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball19);
            }
        }, 1800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball20);
            }
        }, 1900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball21);
            }
        }, 2000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball22);
            }
        }, 2100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball23);
            }
        }, 2200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball24);
            }
        }, 2300);
        answers = new String[] {
                "Your dreams will come true."
        };
        answerText.startAnimation(animationslideintop);
       }
      else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        answerText.setText("");
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball02);
            }
        }, 100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball03);
            }
        }, 200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball04);
            }
        }, 300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball05);
            }
        }, 400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball06);
            }
        }, 500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball07);
            }
        }, 600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball08);
            }
        }, 700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball09);
            }
        }, 800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball10);
            }
        }, 900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball11);
            }
        }, 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball12);
            }
        }, 1100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball13);
            }
        }, 1200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball14);
            }
        }, 1300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball15);
            }
        }, 1400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball16);
            }
        }, 1500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball17);
            }
        }, 1600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball18);
            }
        }, 1700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball19);
            }
        }, 1800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball20);
            }
        }, 1900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball21);
            }
        }, 2000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball22);
            }
        }, 2100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball23);
            }
        }, 2200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball24);
            }
        }, 2300);
        answers = new String[] {
          "Your dreams will NEVER come true."
        };
        answerText.startAnimation(animationslideintop);
       }
       else if(randomNumber == 3) {
        answerText.setText("");
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball02);
            }
        }, 100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball03);
            }
        }, 200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball04);
            }
        }, 300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball05);
            }
        }, 400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball06);
            }
        }, 500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball07);
            }
        }, 600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball08);
            }
        }, 700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball09);
            }
        }, 800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball10);
            }
        }, 900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball11);
            }
        }, 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball12);
            }
        }, 1100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball13);
            }
        }, 1200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball14);
            }
        }, 1300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball15);
            }
        }, 1400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball16);
            }
        }, 1500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball17);
            }
        }, 1600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball18);
            }
        }, 1700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball19);
            }
        }, 1800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball20);
            }
        }, 1900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball21);
            }
        }, 2000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball22);
            }
        }, 2100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball23);
            }
        }, 2200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball24);
            }
        }, 2300);
        answers = new String[] {
          "Your future does not exist."
        };
        answerText.startAnimation(animationslideintop);
       }
    else if(randomNumber == 4) {
        answerText.setText("");
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball02);
            }
        }, 100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball03);
            }
        }, 200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball04);
            }
        }, 300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball05);
            }
        }, 400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball06);
            }
        }, 500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball07);
            }
        }, 600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball08);
            }
        }, 700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball09);
            }
        }, 800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball10);
            }
        }, 900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball11);
            }
        }, 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball12);
            }
        }, 1100);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball13);
            }
        }, 1200);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball14);
            }
        }, 1300);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball15);
            }
        }, 1400);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball16);
            }
        }, 1500);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball17);
            }
        }, 1600);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball18);
            }
        }, 1700);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball19);
            }
        }, 1800);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball20);
            }
        }, 1900);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball21);
            }
        }, 2000);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball22);
            }
        }, 2100);
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                    ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball23);
              }
             }, 2200);
              handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     ball.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball24);
               }
             }, 2300);
             answers = new String[] {
               "You will be slaughtered. Brutally."
             };
             answerText.startAnimation(animationslideintop);
         }
     }


   public static Predictions get()

   {   
       if (predictions == null) {
           predictions = new Predictions();
       }
       return predictions;
  }

   public String getPrediction() {
    return answers[0];
 }

}
```

Here is the error log:

```
Logcat: 09-05 00:04:28.173  24524-24524/<MyPackage> I/art﹕ Late-enabling
-Xcheck:jni 09-05 00:04:28.543  24524-24544/<MyPackage> D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true 09-05 00:04:28.572  24524-24524/<MyPackage> D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ecc750, tid 24524 09-05 00:04:28.596  24524-24524/<MyPackage> D/Atlas﹕ Validating map... 09-05 00:04:28.611  24524-24524/<MyPackage> E/SensorManager﹕ Exception dispatching input event. 09-05 00:04:28.611  24524-24524/<MyPackage> D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 09-05 00:04:28.613  24524-24524/<MyPackage> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: <MyPackage>, PID: 24524
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at <MyPackage>.Predictions.<init>(Predictions.java:20)
            at <MyPackage>.Predictions.get(Predictions.java:518)
            at <MyPackage>.CrystalBall$1.onSensorChanged(CrystalBall.java:56)
            at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:405)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: please create a minimal verifiable example

Comment: Please post your logcat of the crash!

Comment: you do not appear to be initializing your `ball` or `answerText` member variables.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information I am new here. This application is supposed to be a crystal ball. Every time the device is shook, it calls the predictions method. For some reason every time it tries being run, it force closes.

Comment: If there's a force close, try to check if your testing device can handle the ram usage of the application. This will not produce any error on AS I believe.

Comment: @iagreen This may be a very stupid question, but how do I initialize them? I tried ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball); and the fineviewbyid was in red for some reason

Comment: `answerText` and `ball` not initialized

Comment: How can I initialize answerText and ball?

Comment: from where you call the prediction class? from activity?

Comment: @arun Yes from the main class. In this project it is called CrystalBall.java

Comment: Inflate the layout containing the answerTetx and ball also pass the activity reference to predicition class that is if you are calling the prediction class from an activity

Comment: @user3697974 CrystalBall is an activity then you initialize answerText and ball there, and pass the  answerText and ball views to the prediction class.

Comment: You should REALLY look at how you coded this and probably use arrays to hold the integer array of resource ids. And also use more modularization, you are having too much code duplication that can be simplified by finding the commonalities. This makes the code unreadable. Also don't post your real application package, I have taken the liberty of censoring your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get the `context` of your activity and then try to find the XML id of the layout you're referring to using `findViewById` method.

So, for example, you could modify your code into something like

```
private Predictions(Context context) {
    ball = (ImageView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ball_image_view);
    answerText = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);

    // The rest of the code here ...
}

public static Predictions get(Context context) {   
    if (predictions == null) {
        predictions = new Predictions(context);
    }
    return predictions;
}
```

But performance wise, this is still not good enough. Generally, you should only call `findViewById` once. Therefore, a better approach would be trying to find these elements in your main activity, then pass it into the `Prediction` class.

Comment: I think ball = (ImageView)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.ball_image_view)

Answer (score 0):

check your android manifest file , according to your problem there is problem with your android manifest file